# Deleted User Actions

Tags: discussion, deleted-accounts

Someone recently downvoted something on stackoverflow, and then the user was deleted. Because of the deletion, I'm not sure what was downvoted or why, as there is no link provided like there are for every other action in my timeline.
is there a way to figure out what was downvoted?
this seems like a pretty easy way to troll someone.

Comment: How is this a way to troll someone? The downvote was removed along with the user - is it really necessary to see what the vote was for? Why?

Comment: You need to get 125 rep in order to downvote. That's a rather high-effort troll.

Comment: i would like to see it. because i want to. do i need to justify it? seems odd it just hits your score and you don't know why. high-effort troll is still trollollollollolloll

Comment: I still don't see the trolling part? When the user is deleted, *the downvote is gone, too*. The hit to your score is reversed.

Comment: no it wasn't. i see it right now

Comment: According to your history, you appear confused. A user was removed, which causes all of their votes to be retracted. They had likely *upvoted* one of your posts previously, causing you to now lose the 10 reputation you earned from it.

Comment: If your enemy is so invested in the process of harassing you that he will spend days creating, gaining rep for, and then deleting _multiple_ SO accounts, you probably have more than just votes on SO to worry about.

Comment: maybe i do have it wrong. agreed about more to worry about as well.

Comment: I also don't know how identifying the post would help you identify the person or determine whether it was trolling or not.

Comment: i wanted to know the question, the person would just be added boneus

Comment: How does knowing the question help you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An easy way to to troll? I don't really see it that way. As noted in comments to your post, it takes 125 rep gained in order to downvote. All for one downvote, because if the downvotes were serial downvotes then the script would reverse them.

This is not trolling, it has even happened to me (although it only happens once every 3 months, I had to go back to October to find this).

[image]

That being said, I do agree that it can be interesting to figure out what vote was removed. It gives the time, but nothing else. It would really be nice if one part of the report would link to the place where reputation changed (either from a removed downvote or upvote or other modification).

Comment: It turns out the user was confused with something else

Comment: Why does it matter what vote was removed? Really? What are you going to do with that information? The reality is, someone up-voted one of your answers (who knows for what reason), and then the user quit or was forcefully remove. How does it help you to know which answer of yours they had up-voted?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - It doesn't really matter, just a few points either way. But sometimes people (and myself) get curious is all.

Comment: But it's "a few points" no matter which specific post it had belonged to.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I am a fan of pattern recognition. Little bits of data are interesting to me. So, if one of my posts on an older post with a lot of views gets a vote removed from a user removal then that makes sense because it had the highest probability. However, if a post with only 1 vote was removed then that would make me curious if my post there was accurate or needed improvement. If it happened repeatedly to smaller count posts then there would be more randomness then if it happened to a large vote post. Just analysis is all, like I said, mostly out of curiosity.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I wouldn't really be looking to see which user was removed. I highly doubt that trolling is involved in this scenario. It could be nice to be able to review my content in these situations was all I was saying - this is not a feature request in any form.

Comment: Why do you think the removal of a user would have anything at all to do with the quality of your post? They could have voted on 500 posts, and all of those people would have a similar event on their timelines. Do you think all of those posts had some quality issue, and that was why the user quit or their account was destroyed? Users are going to get deleted, and there is absolutely no reason to try to associate that with the posts they voted on.

Comment: But that's what I'm saying - the user was deleted. It has nothing to do with your post. They just happened to have voted on it at some point. This is very different from, say, an un-upvote.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I would say that you are more intent on trolling than this entire situation with user removal and their associated voting. I realize that a removed vote as a result of a user removal has nothing to do with the post. But that is not my point.  It is interesting to analyze. Also note that beyond the picture shown, I did include any modification to reputation including downvoting.

Comment: Huh? How am I "intent on trolling"? I'm merely saying that identifying the post(s) that a removed user had voted on does not help you in any way. Let me put it another way - let's say that 10 points for `User was removed` was [from this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19101503/how-do-i-make-a-nonexistent-non-member-non-global-method-invocable-without-us/19102837#19102837). So that used to be +2, now it's +1. What are you going to do now with that information?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - You asked me the same question several different ways, and you do it here again with your response. That is how you are intent on trolling.  How many times do I have to answer the same question? It helps me analyze my content and observe the occurrence of an event. What I would do is exactly what I already explained.